# Can I self-publish a book on the Kindle store when I'm under 18?

Tags: legal, kindle, amazon, young-author

I'm wondering if I can publish a comic on the Kindle store! It's because me and my friends made a comic and I've now re-drawn everything on my computer and I've looked into this and it says I need to be like 18 I think! I was wondering if I could still do it even if I need my parents' permission! Also if I need my parents' permission and if they have to sign something. If something bad happened would they get fined? Furthermore, if you know anything they can get fined for! Please tell me.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! We've got a couple of questions already about publishing a young age, including [this one](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/18591/23927), but I don't think they're relevant to your particular scenario. Feel free to take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yeah, I agree.  At first I was sure this was a duplicate but it's more about the legal aspects of publishing when you're a minor, which I don't think we've covered (if we have, someone please point it out).

Comment: And yes, welcome to Writing, Ashraf.  We love having writers of all ages here.

Comment: Have you considered publishing it elsewhere such on webtoons which specialises in comics?

Comment: Well, I've considered other websites but I'd rather use the Kindle App because I trust amazon.

Comment: Instead of Kindle, I suggest you look into Comixology.  There is a UK/EU version and it's owned by Amazon.  It's a platform for e-comics and they're all Kindle compatible.  It allows readers to buy individual issues or a subscription to a comics series (they're only charged as each issue comes out).  People looking for comics to buy are much more likely to find you there.  Another good e-comic distributor is Drive-Thru Comics.  They're independently owned and very trustworthy.  You can put your comic in multiple places.

Comment: So of they buy it on there it will be In  their kindle library as well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, yes.  My husband's comic is on Comixology (and Drive-Thru) and I think it's easily read on any device.  I just read the PDF the publisher sends us, so haven't tested it myself.

Comment: TIP: You get notified of a new comment here if it's on a post you wrote.  I only saw your comment cause I checked the page.  To let someone know there's a comment they should see, type @ then start typing their username and click on it when it pops up (which only works if they've contributed to the thread).

Comment: Comixology is the largest, and there are many other small ones I've not investigated as my publisher deals with the distribution aspect.  It is multi-device functional.  However, unlike Amazon, my understanding it that Comixology is not simply a platform; you have to apply to be published there and the work needs to meet their editorial standards.

Comment: @El Cadejo is it extremely hard to reach their standards?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer that question, as I have not self-published.

Comment: @ElCadejo Okay, I will look more into this but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

## Amazon allows your parent to publish your book for you

> 4.1 Eligibility. You must have an active Program account in order to participate in the Program. You represent that you are at least 18
>   years old (or the age of majority where you reside, whichever is
>   older) and that you are able to form a legally binding contract. A
>   parent or guardian of a minor can open a KDP account and be the
>   Publisher of the minor’s Book. (From Kindle Direct Publishing [Terms
>   and Conditions](https://kdp-eu.amazon.com/agreement?token=eyJjbGllbnRJZCI6ImtpbmRsZV9kaXJlY3RfcHVibGlzaGluZyIsImRvY3VtZW50SWQiOiJrZHAiLCJjYW5jZWxVcmwiOiJodHRwczovL2tkcC5hbWF6b24uY29tIiwiY2xpZW50TG9jYWxlIjoiTkEiLCJkaXNwbGF5UGFyYW1zIjpudWxsfQ%7CeyJtYXRlcmlhbFNlcmlhbCI6MSwiaG1hYyI6IjNVTU9oejdYTENWY1dsMUZEWWQwYnRZN3FNR1FxOEJxVHpyaWhYS2dGVWM9IiwianNvbkhtYWMiOnRydWUsInR5cGUiOiJSRUFEX09OTFkiLCJhY2NlcHQiOmZhbHNlfQ&language=en_US))

Yes, this means your parent takes on liability for your work.  Your parent would also collect any money from sales.

This is not the same thing as getting your parent's permission.  The account you need in order to publish must be in your parent's name.

The other issue is that your book has multiple authors, but you can only post it under one account.  My suggestion is that one of you (probably you) is the primary author and that person's parent owns the account.

First, write out a contract.  The contract spells out who owns the copyright, how you split up money, and what happens if a publisher wants to purchase your comic. You might think this is all unnecessary.  Because what are the chances you'll make money and, besides, you all trust each other anyway.

Do it anyway.

Seriously, **never publish without a written contract.**  Just sitting down and hashing out the terms is enough usually to make sure what's obvious to you is exactly the same as what's obvious to your friends.

Once the contract is to everyone's liking, print out enough copies for everyone and order a bunch of pizza or Indian food or something.  Have every author sign every copy.  As minors, your signatures are not legally binding, but it's important to show that you have read the contact and take it seriously.  Next, have one parent of each author also sign.  Everyone keeps one copy (plus you can photograph one fully signed copy and keep it in the cloud).  Now you can eat!

A sample contract might read:

> [A's mom] will set up the Amazon account and publish [comic name] in
>   the Kindle store.  Any expenses must be approved ahead of time by the
>   group and the person will be reimbursed first out of any proceeds.  If
>   there is anything else left, it gets divided up this way: A gets 40%,
>   B gets 20%, C gets 20%, D gets 10%, E gets 10%.

And so forth.

If your comics get popular enough that you're each getting more than about $20US, find a cheap lawyer and make a better contract than your simple one.

Being fined isn't really an issue with publishing as a minor.  It's not illegal.  It's just that your signature isn't binding and any contracts you make without your parents don't count.  The reason to make a contract with your friends (with their legally binding parental signatures) is in case you all disagree about something.  "Why is A getting more money than I am?"  "I don't want my work on Kindle anymore: take it down!"  "I'm going to publish the comic at this other place and keep all the money."

Cross your t's and dot your i's and you'll be fine.  Congrats on writing the comic and good luck with it!

Comment: I know this question is stupid but do I how do I get these contracts. I know I could just ask my parents but I'm very curious.

Comment: @AshrafIslam  Just type it out on your computer and print it.  All you really need at this stage is for all of you to sit down and agree to stuff.  I can not tell you how many times I was sure of an agreement with a friend, family member, roommate, etc and it turned out what was in their head was different from what was in mine.  Don't take chances.  Just decide what you're gonna do and write it down.

Comment: @AshrafIslam Asking about contracts with multiple authors is actually a great question and really should be separate.  Perhaps you'd like to start a new question that asks only that?

Comment: The other important thing a contract should address is what happens if someone wants to leave the project. I've seen group creative projects have issues where a member vanished without leaving permission for the other authors to use the characters they created, hamstringing the project.  Hash out default rules for what is and isn't allowed ahead of time.

Comment: How you get a contract: Agree on its content with the other parties. Type the contract (specify who the parties are and what the contract binds and entitles each party to). Print one copy for each party of the contract. Have all parties (or their legal representative, e. g. a parent) sign all copies (include the date of signing). Let each party keep a copy. Store your copy safely.